Trouble running react-google-drive-picker in Django
I'm attempting to implement a google drive picker in my django + react project:


import React from 'react';
import { Button, Card, Image } from 'antd';
import useDrivePicker from 'react-google-drive-picker';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const { REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY } = process.env;

const Upload = () => {
  const [openPicker, data, authResponsive] = useDrivePicker();

  const upload = (data) => {
    console.log("uploading")
  };

  const handleOpenPicker = () => {
    try {
      openPicker({
        clientId: REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        developerKey: REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        viewId: 'DOCS_VIDEOS',
        showUploadView: true,
        showUploadFolders: true,
        supportDrives: true,
        multiselect: true,
        callbackFunction: (data) => {
          upload(data)
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', padding: '20px' }}>
      <h2>Select Videos from Google Drive</h2>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={() => handleOpenPicker()} style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
        Open Drive Picker
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Upload;



I'm serving this using django, while running this in development (by running npm run start and opening http://localhost:3000) the google-picker works as expected. However when running running in in django by collecting static and serving it from http://localhost:8000, suddenly the popup will not open. Can anyone help me with what I'm missing here ? This is some of my django cors + csrf settings :
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = env.list(
    'http://localhost:8000',
    'DJANGO_CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST',
    default=[BASE_FRONTEND_URL]
)
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000',     'http://localhost:8000']

